# why so Many processes going in chrome at once?

Tags: google-chrome

this explanation is baloney:https://www.howtogeek.com/124218/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-open-processes/.
I have no plug ins and only one page open and not accessing any web sites but Chrome has 15 processes going. Chrome is just a memory hog!

Answer (score -2):

G-Crome is a lighter browser in comparing to other such products.Even though no web-page is opened for google crome to work it has to run several program asynchronously.For example it should check if the n/w is open, if any malicious ssn connection is trying to sneak in your pc/laptop etc.That resembles the count of so many processes.